# Compare 2 CSV files with numeric values

Tags: python, csv

Compare two csv files and required result need to be shared like diff in numeric values, field value type, count of records etc.

input file A (`XYZ_20190908.csv`):

```
Name,F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10
K1 data,8470,37609,18413,13799,24946,27870,376,24573,27247,41569,687
Total VoLte Traffic,130944.126111,689417.554722,208189.652500,196002.846944,223558.256111,501265.626667,2508.617222,200054.686389,174738.403056,394327.636389,2017.576667
K2 Data,11163.201111,52680.898056,19920.813333,15878.103611,18247.582222,40295.689444,264.738333,17732.341111,15486.259444,32662.475833,199.080278
K3 Data,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
K4 Data,11163.201111,52680.898056,19920.813333,15878.103611,18247.582222,40295.689444,264.738333,17732.341111,15486.259444,32662.475833,199.080278
```

input file B (`XYZ_20190909.csv`):

```
Name,F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,F10
Calculation,CHN,GUJ,HR,KOL,MAH,MUM,PJB,ROB,TN,UPE,UPW
K1 data,8467,37622,18418,14138,24943,27914,370,24621,27310,41565,687
K2 Data,199379.472222,NaN,241390.289167,264378.881667,292310.146944,774915.508056,3560.825278,212203.013611,213419.833611,403226.574444,2023.039167
K3 Data,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
K4 Data,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

Output :

1. difference in each value for the corresponding fields.
2. if all the values are "NaN" error
3. compare value in file A with file B, if the value corresponding to the
   position in both file with different data have different data type (like file A having 52680.898056 and in file B the value is NaN) should display error

Need help.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please refer to [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Put more details of the issue that you are facing. Include the relevant code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Pandas library. It has some useful methods to deal with these kind of problems, like `to_csv` and `read_csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(`XYZ_20190908.csv`)
df2 = pd.read_csv(`XYZ_20190909.csv`)
```

Make sure they have the same structure of columns and indexes so that you can concat or merge them in a desired way

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

which will make sense only if rows and/or columns are logically aligned.

After merge you can proceed with any pandas operations. Specifically something to point you direction into your questions a) b) and c):

```
df['diff']=df.col_df1 - df.col_df2
df.isna()
df.apply(lambda x: if type(x.col_df1) == type(x.col_df2) True else False, axis = 1)
```

however the question is too broad and data structure is too imprecise to properly answer your question.

Comment: Live server and can't install pandas